# Error when generating a certificate: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: certificate, native-methods

When calling this:

```
Check(NativeMethods.CryptAcquireContextW(
                out providerContext,
                containerName,
                null,
                1, // PROV_RSA_FULL
                8)); // CRYPT_NEWKEYSET
```

I get this:

The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002): Stack Trace: at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
 at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)

It seems to be similar to this
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/feaf03f7-51a8-48d6-825f-e04c4ff2ef3a

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when doing this from a web application. For me, the solution was to change the app pool identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService (Advanced Settings of the app pool). Running IIS7 on Windows 2008 Server R2.

Comment: This fixed it for me on Windows server 2016, with .net Core 2.1 also.....